Type of Paint for concrete shed?
I have tried power washing this shed but it still looks dirty. I would like to paint it white. Any ideas what kind of paint I should purchase?


You need to power wash it with bleach, let it sit an hour, then soap, then hit it with some sort of non-abrasive scrubbing sponge, then rinse.    The paint has held up really nice so if you clean it well the new paint will last a while.    Don't repaint something that nice without a thorough washing.    Note - cleaning it likely will take longer than painting it.

Try a Masonry and stucco paint. Usually 2 coats are needed.
The black marks can still be mildew on the old paint. Wash the spots with 50/50 bleach and water and dry well before painting.
